# Why can't I get any info on the dom object using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, dom, fancybox, lightbox

I have a function that is run to activate fancybox on a user click.  :

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({'titlePosition': 'inside','titleFormat': formatTitle});
```

This calls this function:

```
function formatTitle(title, index,href) {
     alert($(this).get(0).tagName);
     return title;
}
```

Now I want to format the title by accessing an array I have made that has hrefs in it for each fancybox item.  To access it, I want to be able to get the class of the element, since the class is used as a  the array reference e.g. `myArray[class]=hrefValue.`

Here is the html:

```
<a class="fancybox" title="A microsite designed to work alongside a marketing campaign to get vacant posts filled in Bradford Royal Infirmary's Radiology department" href="images/assets/web_design/lookdeeper_fullsize.jpg">
       <img alt="thumbnail of Look Deeper" src="images/assets/web_design/lookdeeper_thumbnail.png">
</a>
```

But I cannot get a reference to that class.  My alert is showing undefined.  Yet if I just alert $(this) it alerts 'object'.  So I'm thinking, is something other than a dom element calling the formatTitle function, and is that why I cannot get any reference to the dom?

Comment: `$(this)` may not be what you think it is, do a `console.log( $(this) )` to make sure it's what you think it is first.

Comment: Using Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools would be easier than printing values in `alert();` Just use `console.log()` or other `console` methods

Comment: I do use firebug, but I'm not sure where I find the console

Comment: While using firebug you should propably first activate the first firebug tab (Console) ;)

Comment: Instead of the alert in your code do `console.log( $this )`

Comment: ok it tells me the name of the current page.  this is only relevant on clicking of the element that loads the fancybox.  Here is the page if it helps: http://nicolaelvin.com/web_design.php

Answer (score 0):

If you reference your array by numbers and not ids you can get hold of the element from within the formatTitle using currentIndex:

```
function formatTitle(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
 alert(myArray[currentIndex]);
 return myArray[currentIndex];
}
```

If this is what you wanted